# all plugin not showing up in plugin list in nopCommerce 4.20

Tags: asp.net-core, plugins, backend, nopcommerce

i m working with nopcommerce 4.20.
All plugin was working but after i use tfs "source controller" ,all plugin not showing up in plugin list
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always good to keep the .gitignore file as same as the nopCommerce core team. You can get it from [gitignore of nopCommerce core team](https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce/blob/develop/.gitignore)